# set android textView drawableEnd programmatically

Tags: android, layout

How to set the `android:drawableEnd` of `TextView` from the java code?
the `setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(int,int,int,int)` can be used on left, right, top and bottom only. how to set `drawableEnd`?

Answer (score 18):

To set drawableend programatically,Use below code. Worked for me.

```
   rowTextView.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.ic_call_black_24dp, 0);
```

Answer (score 8):

There is a similar method called setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(int, int, int, int) where the parameters refer to start, top, end, bottom

You need to have **min API level 17** or higher though.

Answer (score 5):

If you use kotlin, I can advise the following extensions for EditText interaction with Drawables.

```
var EditText.drawableStart: Drawable?
    get() = compoundDrawablesRelative?.get(0)
    set(value) = setDrawables(start = value)

var EditText.drawableTop: Drawable?
    get() = compoundDrawablesRelative?.get(1)
    set(value) = setDrawables(top = value)

var EditText.drawableEnd: Drawable?
    get() = compoundDrawablesRelative?.get(2)
    set(value) = setDrawables(end = value)

var EditText.drawableBottom: Drawable?
    get() = compoundDrawablesRelative?.get(2)
    set(value) = setDrawables(bottom = value)


fun EditText.setDrawables(
    start: Drawable? = null,
    top: Drawable? = null,
    end: Drawable? = null,
    bottom: Drawable? = null
) = setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(start, top, end, bottom)
```

After adding these extensions, you can work with Drawables as follows:

```
drawableEnd = context.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_close_black)
```

I think that here it is necessary to use the method 'setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds'. Because inside the implementation, it sets the values for the variables mDrawableEnd and mDrawableStart. These variables are substituted in left and rigt, if not null, this is seen in the example of such code inside the TextView:

```
if (mIsRtlCompatibilityMode) {
                // Use "start" drawable as "left" drawable if the "left" drawable was not defined
                if (mDrawableStart != null && mShowing[Drawables.LEFT] == null) {
                    mShowing[Drawables.LEFT] = mDrawableStart;
                    mDrawableSizeLeft = mDrawableSizeStart;
                    mDrawableHeightLeft = mDrawableHeightStart;
                }
                // Use "end" drawable as "right" drawable if the "right" drawable was not defined
                if (mDrawableEnd != null && mShowing[Drawables.RIGHT] == null) {
                    mShowing[Drawables.RIGHT] = mDrawableEnd;
                    mDrawableSizeRight = mDrawableSizeEnd;
                    mDrawableHeightRight = mDrawableHeightEnd;
                }
            }
```

Comment: `drawableBottom` should be `compoundDrawablesRelative[3]`, shouldn't it?